# What is the Kotlin equivalent to C# 8's async enumerable?

Tags: kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

C# 8 now has [IAsyncEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8#a-tour-through-async-enumerables). Is there a Kotlin equivalent to this? For instance, in C# you can `await foreach(...)` now (with `IAsyncEnumerable`):

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    await foreach(var dt in new Seconds().Take(10))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
    }
}

public class Seconds : IAsyncEnumerable<DateTime>
{
    public class FooEnumerator : IAsyncEnumerator<DateTime>
    {
        public DateTime Current { get; set; }
        public async ValueTask DisposeAsync() {}
        public async ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Current = DateTime.Now;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public IAsyncEnumerator<DateTime> GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => new FooEnumerator(); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [Asynchronous Flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html), which seems to be the closest equivalent.

A similar example would be:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    seconds().take(10).collect {
        println(it)
    }
}

fun seconds() = flow<Instant> {
    while (true) {
        delay(1000L)
        emit(Instant.now())
    }
}
```

<sup>I'm using [`kotlinx-coroutines-core`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines) version [1.3.9](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core/1.3.9)</sup>